# Change in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, repository

I am using gerrit for my project. I am automating some of my work which includes identifying the gerrit commit cherry-picked to local machine. 
for example: I have  several changes uploaded on gerrit for review. I cherry picked those changes to local machine.
     Is there any way i can find out which changes are cherry picked and which are not?? I can compare revisions of cherry picked changes with the one on gerrit, but the problem is revision changes if parent changes.[revision is calculated by using different factors like diff,parent etc]

Which is the unique thing about gerrit change that doesn't change even if I cherry pick changes locally.

Comment: I think you can query the changeId and patchset number for each commit, which can identify a change uniquely. check the [doc](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3021/documentation/2.1.4/cmd-query.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The [Change-Id](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/user-changeid.html) footer line in the commit message is unique for each commit (at least for a particular project/branch combo). The SHA-1 can't be used since it, as you've discovered, changes after a cherry-pick. To find the change id of an uploaded commit the [`query` SSH command](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/cmd-query.html) and [/changes REST endpoint](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/rest-api-changes.html#get-change) are useful.

Theoretically you could also use `git cherry` or `git patch-id` to compare commits, but I don't think it would be very practical in this case.

Comment: Okay. so for that all changes should contain Change ID in their commit message. Right? What if Change ID is not present??

Comment: Then you'll probably have to resort to `git cherry` and/or `git patch-id`. If this is a problem you should flip the configuration switch that causes Gerrit to require Change-Id lines for uploaded changes. I don't see any reason not to enforce this.